# How to implement remote control GPIO Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio

Good afternoon.
I decided to build a small machine based on Raspberry, running through wifi.
Wrote a simple web muzzle, which requests turn on and off the engines. Not sure if this is the best option, constantly rush inquiries.
The question is, can there be any sort of or something like that you can remotely control the GPIO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plenty of ways if you share a network (wired or wireless) with the Pi.

Have a look at my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) especially the Python [module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html).  That will allow you to control the GPIO from another Windows, Mac, Android, Linux machine as long as it can run Python.  Each Pi you wish to control must have the pigpio [daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) running on it.

Also have a look at [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which lets you do the same but is more suitable and better documented for beginners.

Answer (score 5):

The pigpio library supports remote GPIO: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/

The GPIO Zero library also supports using pigpio as the pin driver, so you can use the GPIO Zero API with pigpio features. See the sections on remote GPIO: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html and https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes_remote_gpio.html